# AWS Managed Airflow Workers: How can I know the IOPS or Network Limitations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, io, airflow, cpu

If I look at the different Airflow Environment classes (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/environment-class.html), I can see how much RAM and vCPUs each worker has but I'm unsure about Network limitations or I/O limitations. Should I be able to tell based on that or could those be independent?

My tasks each read a few MB from S3  and copy a few MB to the /tmp/ directory when starting. Is that an unreasonable amount of data if 10 tasks are started at the exact same time? I'm seeing CPUUtilization and sometimes Memory spikes only when tasks are started concurrently so I want to consider this as a potential cause but I don't know if it could possibly be enough to cause issues. CloudWatch only has metrics on CPUUtilization and Memory so I don't have insights into other limitations.